# Removing UIImageView from UIScrollView

Tags: iphone, ios, uiscrollview, uiimageview

My app consists of an image gallery. It is a scroll view which displays pics retrieved from the sqlite db. User can scroll the images, add or delete images etc. I can add a picture to the gallery dynamically. But the problem comes when I need to implement the delete functionality. I use the following code but even after calling `removeFromSuperView` the image is not getting removed from the scrollview.

```
-(void)deleteDeck{ 

if(selectedEditDeck!=0){
    [deck deleteSelectedDeck:selectedEditDeck]; //deleting from database
  
   //problem starts here ***
    [(UIImageView*)[decksGallery viewWithTag:selectedEditDeck-1]removeFromSuperview];
    [self loadGallery];
    selectedEditDeck=0;
  //Ends here*****
    
    [tableData release];
    tableData=[NSMutableArray array];
    [self showCardNamesinTable];
    [aTableView reloadData];
}
```

I have already created the uiscrollview in the loadview method. Then to refresh the view after every deletion and addition of images so that I can display the updated gallery, I use the following piece of code:

```
-(void)loadGallery{                                                                                //Reloading all for adding a single deck image.

//Database part****
NSString *sqlStr = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"select first_card from decksTable"]; 
char *sql = (char*)[sqlStr UTF8String];
kidsFlashCardAppDelegate *appDelegate = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
NSMutableArray *galleryImagesArray=[appDelegate.dbConnection fetchColumnFromTable:sql col:0];
NSArray *sysPaths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask,YES);
NSString *docDirectory = [sysPaths objectAtIndex:0];
numberofImages = [galleryImagesArray count];
printf("number is %d",numberofImages);//Database part of code ends here
```

//In the following fragment of code I add images to UIscrollView

```
    for (int i = 0; i < [galleryImagesArray count]; i++) {
    CGFloat yOrigin = i * 65;
    NSString *filePath = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@", docDirectory,[galleryImagesArray objectAtIndex:i]];
    galleryImage = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(yOrigin+140, 15,50,50 )];
    //galleryImage.tag=[galleryImagesArray count];
    galleryImage.tag=i;
    printf("THE TAG IS %d",galleryImage.tag);
    galleryImage.clipsToBounds=YES;
    galleryImage.layer.cornerRadius=11.0;
    galleryImage.backgroundColor=[UIColor clearColor];
    galleryImage.image =[UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:filePath];
    [decksGallery addSubview:galleryImage];
    [galleryImage release];
}
decksGallery.contentSize = CGSizeMake(115*[galleryImagesArray count], 80);
//[decksGallery reloadInputViews];
```

Comment: Sorry for the way of formatting of code... n btw I use the tag of the imageview to refer to them while deletion...

Comment: Can you put a break point and verify that your selectedDeck is being set and that code for deleting the deck from database is getting executed. After deleting check if fresh load from the database is again giving the same image.

Comment: no i store the image path in db and retrieve it.....actually the image gets removed when i remove it sequentially..say i have five images...when i start deleting from image with tag 5...it s getting deleted....but when i do it randomly it s not getting removed..n one more thing when i select the image wid tag zero..tat s the first img..all the images are gettn removed...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure your `[decksGallery viewWithTag:selectedEditDeck-1]` is not returning `nil` and the image was actually deleted from your db before the refresh code running.

In addition, you are setting `imageView.tag = i;` in your creation code, since the `i` would be 0 which is the tag's default value for every UIView, you'd better fix your creation code as well.

Comment: No it s not returning nil. And regarding what u have said about tag;s default value,could u please explain more on that ??

Comment: You'd better set .tag like this: imageView.tag = kImageViewStartAt + i; , which kImageViewStartAt is #defined as a large number, 1000 for example. And you can get the imageView by using [*** viewWithTag:kImageViewStartAt + selectedDeck - 1];

Comment: About your question itself, I think maybe you should check if the imageView you got with tag is the view you want to remove. Also you'd better check about how many imageViews your decksGallery have by using NSLog("SubView Count: %@", [[decksGallery subViews] count]); and see if the count is correct.

Comment: Thanks a lot....I checked wid this..NSLog("SubView Count: %@", [[decksGallery subViews] count]); there were more number of subView than i expected. I have been calling the for loop again n again wid out removing subviews...Thanks a lot once again for ur tip...It worked like a charm :D :)

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to remove the image from your imageView, you can also do imageView.image = nil;

```
UIImageView*imageView = (UIImageView*)[decksGallery viewWithTag:selectedEditDeck-1];
[imageView removeFromSuperview];
imageView = nil;
```

Comment: can you check what is in the imageView object when your breakpoint hit the [imageView removeFromSuperview]; line...